# How to select multiple TYPEs using Solr in Alfresco?

Tags: solr, alfresco

I have a following CMIS query and need to perform it in Solr query language

```
SELECT * FROM  ecmcnddoc:common_attr_aspect WHERE (cmis:objectTypeId='D:ecmcndintregst:nd_int_reg_standards' OR cmis:objectTypeId='D:ecmcndcountryst:nd_country_standards')
```

The problem is how to get two TYPES together in Solr?
In case of single type it should be

```
search +TYPE:"ecmcndintregst:nd_int_reg_standards"
```

but how to get them both ecmcndintregst:nd_int_reg_standards and ecmcndcountryst:nd_country_standards ?

Comment: `TYPE:ecmcndintregst:"nd_int_reg_standards" OR TYPE:ecmcndcountryst:"nd_country_standards"` - ìf the field name is `TYPE:ecmcndintregst`, you'll have to escape the colon: `TYPE\:ecmcndintregst`. Doesn't this work? You also asked a very similar question previously which there were a few questions and suggestions for - feel free to update with any details on why those suggestions didn't work.

Comment: I have no idea what the field name is, because I use Alfresco. The types are named:  "ecmcndintregst:nd_int_reg_standards" and "ecmcndcountryst:nd_country_standards"

Comment: You can see what the actual field names are by querying your Solr instance directly. One part will be returned as the field name and one part as the value. If the field is named `TYPE`, you'll need to escape the second `:` instead (and the quotes if they are part of the value).